# how to remove nsdictionary from keychain for replacing

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsdata, keychain

I am storing and loading a serialized nsdictionary to the keychain as in this post ([Store NSDictionary in keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948698/store-nsdictionary-in-keychain)), but I need to be able to update/edit the dictionary contents so I would like to delete it and re add.

I just dont know how to do it. I have the following code taken from the above post:

```
    KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"arbitraryId" accessGroup:nil]
    NSString *error;
    //The following NSData object may be stored in the Keychain
    NSData *dictionaryRep = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:dictionary format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];
    [keychain setObject:dictionaryRep forKey:kSecAttrService];

    //When the NSData object object is retrieved from the Keychain, you convert it back to NSDictionary type
    dictionaryRep = [keychain objectForKey:kSecAttrServce];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:dictionaryRep mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:nil errorDescription:&error];

    SecItemDelete((CFDictionaryRef)dictionaryRep); // doesnt work
```

the values arent deleted from the keychain.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strange place to store the data. You're putting it in `kSecAttrService`, which isn't encrypted. I think you mean to put this in `kSecValueData` (this is the only piece of a keychain item that is encrypted).

That said, there's no need to delete the item. You can just use `[keychain setObject:forKey:]` to update the value whenever you want. `KeychainItemWrapper` automatically detects whether the item exists already, and updates it if it does.

If you want to delete the item using `KeychainItemWrapper`, use `-resetKeychainItem`. This calls `SecItemDelete()` with the correct value. You cannot in general mix-and-match the use of `KeychainItemWrapper` and raw calls to `SecItem*` without a good understanding of the Keychain API and exactly how `KeychainItemWrapper` works.

Answer (score 0):

Although i have never worked on accessing Keychain properties. but by looking at the `SecItemDelete` method in Apple document the expected parameter is a dictionary, in your code you are passing `dictionaryRep` which is a `NSData` type.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/SecItemDelete

Found a question here, hope it might help.

[I want to delete all items in my self created KeyChain on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666727/i-want-to-delete-all-items-in-my-self-created-keychain-on-mac-os-x)